# How to group-by and nest results in each group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I tried to do this:

```
Things.order("name").group("category_name")
```

I was expecting the results to be something like this:

```
[
    {
    "category_name": "Cat1",
    "things":
    [
        { "name": "Cat1_Thing1" },
        { "name": "Cat1_Thing1" }
    ]
},
{
    "category_name": "Cat2",
    "things":
    [
        { "name": "Cat2_Thing3" },
        { "name": "Cat2_Thing4" }
    ]
}
]
```

So I would have expected to get an array of "categories" each with an array of "items" which are within that category. Instead, it appears to give me a list of things, sorted by the field I grouped on.

**Note:** `category_name` is a column in the `thing` table.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
my_grouping = Category.includes(:things).
    select("*").
    group('categories.id, things.id').
    order('name')

=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Category id: 1, name: "Oranges">, #<Category id: 2, name: "Apples">]>
```

Though, you'll still have to access the `Thing` objects via `my_grouping.things`, they'll already be at your hand, and you won't have to wait for the results. This is likely the sort of interaction you're looking for, vs. mapping them into an actual `Array`.

Comment: if my memory is good, it works with mysql, but postgresql will choke on this (impossible to select non-aggregate fields that are not in group by conditions)

Comment: Nope, I use this in Postgresql. Above, `things.id` in the `group` clause resolves that condition.

Comment: ah yeah ? would be great. last time i checked grouping was a pain with AR + postgre

Answer (score 1):

One option is to do the grouping  in Rails (it returns a hash)

```
Things.order("name").group_by(&:category_name)
#=> {"cat1" => [thing1,thing2,..], "cat2" => [thing3,thing4,..],..}
```

Comment: beware, if `category_name` comes from an associated record, you have a N+1 query problem. `group_by` is a pure ruby method, no SQL involved.

Comment: ya that is correct,@Josh M. I assumed `category_name` is a column in the table itself as there is no join the sql query. If it is a different table can you update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, in this example it's a column, not a related table.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord::Base#group performs a SQL GROUP BY. I think, but i'm not sure (depends on your db adapter) that as you don't specify any SELECT clause, you get the first record for each category.

To achieve what you want, there are different ways.

For instance, using `#includes` :

```
Category.includes(:things).map do |category|
  {
    category_name: category.name,
    things:        things.sort_by(&:name).map{|t| {name: t.name} }
  }
end.to_json
```

Note that the standard (albeit often frowned upon) way to serialize models as json is to use (and override if need be) [as_json and to_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json). so you would have something along the lines of this :

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  def as_json( options = {} )
    defaults = { only: :name, root: false, include: {links: {only: :name}} }
    super( defaults.merge(options) )
  end

end
```

Use it like this :

```
Category.includes(:links).map(&:to_json)
```

**EDIT**

As category_name is only a column, you can do :

```
Thing.order( :category_name, :name ).sort_by( &:category_name ).map do |category, things|
  { category_name: category, things: things.map{|t| {name: t.name} } }
end.to_json
```

such thing could belong in the model :

```
def self.sorted_by_category
  order( :category_name, :name ).sort_by( &:category_name ).map do |category, things|
    { category_name: category, things: things.map{|t| {name: t.name} } }
  end 
end
```

so you can do :

```
Thing.sorted_by_category.to_json
```

this way, you can even scope things further :

```
Thing.where( foo: :bar ).sorted_by_category.to_json
```

Comment: Sorry, category_name is just a column, not a related table.